# How to get Circle Hover Effects with CSS Transitions with img tag?

Tags: html, css, effects

I want Circle Hover Effects with CSS Transitions on `<img>` tag without calling the image as background image.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedwf80h/3/)  of the effect I want. But in this fiddle, image is used as a background image. I want same effect, but with image in an `img` tag, not as background image.

```css
.ch-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.ch-img-1 {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/images/5.jpg);
}
.ch-img-2 {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/images/5.jpg);
}
.ch-img-3 {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/images/5.jpg);
}
.ch-info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.ch-info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 65px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ch-info p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.ch-info p a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ch-info p a:hover {
  color: #fff222;
  color: rgba(255, 242, 34, 0.8);
}
.ch-item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 110px rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
@import url('normalize.css');

/* General Demo Style */

body {
  font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
  background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/bg.jpg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.clr {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.container > header {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}
.container > header h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.container > header h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #888;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
/* Header Style */

.codrops-top {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.codrops-top a {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
}
.codrops-top a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}
.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
/* Demo Buttons Style */

.codrops-demos {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.codrops-demos a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(47%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.codrops-demos a:hover {
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}
.codrops-demos a:active {
  background: #fff;
}
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
  color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#f6f6f6', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.support-note span {
  color: #ac375d;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.no-cssanimations .support-note span.no-cssanimations,
.no-csstransforms .support-note span.no-csstransforms,
.no-csstransforms3d .support-note span.no-csstransforms3d,
.no-csstransitions .support-note span.no-csstransitions {
  display: block;
}
.ch-grid {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.ch-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid li {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">

  <ul class="ch-grid">
    <li>
      <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
        <div class="ch-info">
          <h3>Brainiac</h3>
          <p>by Daniel Nyari <a href="http://drbl.in/eODP">View on Dribbble</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="ch-item ch-img-2">
        <div class="ch-info">
          <h3>Vision</h3>
          <p>by Daniel Nyari <a href="http://drbl.in/eNXW">View on Dribbble</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="ch-item ch-img-3">
        <div class="ch-info">
          <h3>Cylon</h3>
          <p>by Daniel Nyari <a href="http://drbl.in/eNXY">View on Dribbble</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: add your code and what you tried so far , _oh god i want so many things too_ ;)

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, it's too hard to understand !!

Comment: can you understand it now??? :) pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pedwf80h/7/

Essentially I've moved the img url from the background to within the li element. Then positioned the img absolutely and used z-index to move it to the back. The li element then uses `overflow: hidden` and `border-radius: 100%` to hide any of the image that goes outside of our li element.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be this can help for you:

```css
.ch-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}
.ch-info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

li img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


.ch-item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 110px rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
@import url('normalize.css');

/* General Demo Style */
body{
 font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
 background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/bg.jpg);
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #333;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
a{
 color: #555;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.clr{
 clear: both;
 padding: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.main{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}
.container > header{
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
}
.container > header h1{
 font-size: 32px;
 line-height: 32px;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #777;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.container > header h2{
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: italic;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
 color: #888;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
/* Header Style */
.codrops-top{
 line-height: 24px;
 font-size: 11px;
 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 z-index: 9999;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.codrops-top a{
 padding: 0px 10px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: #333;
 display: inline-block;
}
.codrops-top a:hover{
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.codrops-top span.right{
 float: right;
}
.codrops-top span.right a{
 float: left;
 display: block;
}
/* Demo Buttons Style */
.codrops-demos{
    text-align:center;
 display: block;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}
.codrops-demos a{
    display: inline-block;
 font-style: italic;
 margin: 0px 4px;
 padding: 0px 6px;
 color: #aaa;
 line-height: 20px; 
 font-size: 13px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.codrops-demos a:hover{
 color: #333;
 background: #fff;
}
.codrops-demos a:active{
 background: #fff;
}
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover{
 background: #f0f0f0;
 border-color: #d9d9d9;
 color: #aaa;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.support-note span{
 color: #ac375d;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0;
}
.no-cssanimations .support-note span.no-cssanimations,
.no-csstransforms .support-note span.no-csstransforms,
.no-csstransforms3d .support-note span.no-csstransforms3d,
.no-csstransitions .support-note span.no-csstransitions{
 display: block;
}
.ch-grid {
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
 content: '';
    display: table;
}

.ch-grid:after {
 clear: both;
}

.ch-grid li {
 width: 220px;
 height: 220px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">

  <ul class="ch-grid">
    <li>
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/images/5.jpg" alt="Vision">
      <div class="ch-item">
        <div class="ch-info">
   
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional reference website...
[Reference link](http://codepen.io/nordstromdesign/pen/gsvJj/)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:700);

body {
  padding-top: 2em;
  background-color: #c02227;
}

.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000;  
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.circle-container:hover .circle {
    transform: rotate3d(45, 45, 0, 180deg);
}

.circle-container:hover .outer-ring {
    transform: rotate3d(45, 0, 0, 180deg);
}

.circle-container:hover .outer-outer-ring {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 45, 0, 180deg);
}

.circle-container, .front, .back {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.circle, .outer-ring, .outer-outer-ring {
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.150, 0.860);
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
}

.front, .back {
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

.front p {
    margin-top: 1.2em;
    font-family: cabin, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #c02227;
}

.back {
    transform: rotate3d(45,45,0,180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
}

.back-logo {
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

.outer-ring {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 191px;
    height: 191px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.outer-outer-ring {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 211px;
    height: 211px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```